# Some commands not working in the script running from the crontab -e

Tags: bash, npm, cron, sudo

I'm running a script from crontab in which I want to set the symbolic link for `npx`. It does some other things which are dependent on the `npx` command itself.  Its running the script as expected on the giving time interval, but its giving me no result for command `which npx` or `whereis npx`. When I try to run the script from terminal directly these commands does generate the correct path.
Note that, `crontab` I'm using is under the root user privilege, i.e set with `sudo crontab -e` and verified with `echo`ing `whoami` inside the script which generate 'root')

Comment: Where is `npx`? By default, cron jobs run with a very minimal `PATH` (usually just `/usr/bin:/bin`), and if it's not in one of the directories in that, `which` won't find it (`whereis` is a little different, but may have a similar issue).

Comment: Hi Gordon, NPX is an executor which comes with the npm, what do you mean by minimal PATH... isnt this script running in the same environment...since I'm able to the correct path of npx (with `which npx`) when I run the script manually, thanks !

Comment: Do you have a `$HOME/.profile` or `$HOME/.bash_rc` where your path is changed?
Try sourcing that file first.

Comment: cron jobs don't run in anything like your normal environment; see [this Q&A](https://superuser.com/questions/784252/crontab-and-binaries-in-usr-local-bin). Also, be aware that environment it does have is root's, not yours.

Answer (score 0):

By default, crontab will run your cron jobs using `sh` which might be the reason you are getting no results.

Try to explicitly change the shell to your default shell by adjusting the crontab entry:

`*/30 * * * * /bin/bash -c "/my_script.sh"`

In this case I changed it to bash, you can change it to your desired shell.

Comment: Hi Shachar, yes, I tried this but couldnt get the expected result, crontab gives no output for `which npx` while running the script manually (under the root access) does, thanks!

Comment: A quick fix would be to specify the full path - however, you might want to just adjust the PATH environment variable for your script.